# Search special character from SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, special-characters

I am searching a specific record from my data base Like "Case Name" and Case name field includes special characters also Like "Case-1" , "Case_1" , "Diana's Case" , etc.

So when I search for specific case name using query

```
select * from TableName where CaseName = 'Case_1'
```

Then I can find it. But problem is here that if I want to search

`select * from TableName where CaseName = 'Diana's Case'`

Then it throws exception because of " ' " character.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double `'` inside string to escape it.

```
select * 
from TableName 
where CaseName = 'Diana''s Case'
```

**[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372401)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  CaseName = 'Diana''s Case'
```

Comment: what if i have more than one ( ' ) in my Name for Example Diana'''''''s Case .???

Comment: I edited the string with this code. and now i am not having problem again.